# Do not remove spaces in kable function

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have developed several regression models and want to present them in a table. The regression coefficients and, behind them, the significance levels are shown in the columns. There is one column for each regression model I have put thethe coefficients and significance levels together with paste.

```
paste(2.44," . ", sep=" ") or paste(1.33," * ", sep=" ") or paste(1.33,"   ", sep=" ")
```

The output when I run the table in R is correct but while using the kable function in RMarkdown the output looks like this:

```
3.99 ***  
 2.44  *   
    4.66
```

But I want to display the results neatly like this:

```
 3.99 ***  
 2.44  *   
 4.66
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not put the stars in a separate column?

Comment: Because there are several regressions to present in the table and when I use separate columns for the stars the table is to wide.

Comment: You need to post a complete example if you want suggestions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946349/do-not-remove-spaces-in-kable-function-with-example/63946986#63946986) with a reproducible example.

The answer I received from @allan-cameron was:  "This is not a `kable` problem. This is how html behaves. If you want to add extra spaces in text you need to add `"&nbsp;"` to your text. Make this your paste separator, and ensure you turn `escape = FALSE` inside kable:"

That solution worked well for me.